# Shorewall: how to redirect traffic on a specific port to a machine on the network?

Tags: linux, firewall

This is stupid... I've read the guides and tried every rule I could think of.

So, let's say I have a machine with shorewall installed.  Whenever traffic comes in on port 7999, it needs to redirect this traffic to another machine entirely on the same port.  Both machines are on the network as peers.  I have two zones defined: `net` and `fw`.

Assume the machine doing the redirect is 192.168.1.1, and the machine needing to be redirected to is 192.168.1.2.  The following rule does not appear to work:

```
DNAT net net:192.168.1.2:7999 tcp 7999
```

I have no idea what's wrong with it.  Literally, it's saying, for any connections to `net` on port `7999`, redirect them out back to `net` to host `192.168.1.2` on port `7999`.  That makes sense, right?  But unfortunately, the rule doesn't seem to do anything.   Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your other machine in the DMZ zone,

After that use this:

```
DNAT   net   dmz:192.168.1.2   tcp   7999
```